# Mantine Ui for component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, system-design, mantine

I'm Developing a Component library for my company internal projects and will use that as a npm package.
I'm using Mantine as a starter and will add customization using tailwind.
I wrote this as a test button just to check things

```
import React from "react";
import { Button as MantineButton } from "@mantine/core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const ButtonTest = ({ label, backgroundColor = "red", handleClick }) => {
  const style = {
    backgroundColor,
    border: "none",
    padding: "10px",
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <MantineButton onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
        {label}
      </MantineButton>
    </div>
  );
};

ButtonTest.prototypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default ButtonTest;
```

and in index file on root in react app I'm exporting this component and then publish this component on npm.

on another app when i tried to use this, it returns this error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`
I know this error is related to MantineProvider but where can i use mantine provider in my code to fix this error
i tried to wrap my app in mantine provider in another project where i'm using this package but still same error.

Comment: I guess you need to wrap your root component with MantineProvide where you have defined the component. Not where you are using it.

Comment: @CodeThing this is my index.js file of src/components

`import ButtonTest from "./ButtonTest";

export {ButtonTest};`
in RollupConfig.js i passed this path.
where should i wrap?

Comment: Try wrapping this button component itself inside return.

Comment: If you are suggesting like this
`<MantineProvider>
      <MantineButton onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
        {label}
      </MantineButton>
    </MantineProvider>`
It still gave same error

Comment: @Hasseb Ali, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to the same issue. After looking into it I managed to trace the issue to the fact that I was building my typescript package to common js.
With `tsc` being used to compile my typescript code, I changed my `tsconfig.json` accordingly to compile to ESM after which I was able to successfully import my package component and use it within my project.
Below is my `tsonfig.json` after the changes were made:

```json
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020", // <-- Set to ESM
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist/esm",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types"
  }
}
```